# Conversion between org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile and org.springframework.core.io.Resource

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-mvc, multipart

I am trying to pass a resource as a @RequestPart to my controller.

```
@RequestPart(name = "resource", required = false) Resource multipartFile,
```

It seem to work good in my integration tests where I pass it as a Resource:

```
ByteArrayResource resource = new ByteArrayResource(new byte[] {65, 66, 67});    
MultipartBodyBuilder b = new  MultipartBodyBuilder();
b.part("resource", resource, MediaType.APPLICATION_PDF);
return webClient.post().uri(getUri()
                       .contentType(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
                       .syncBody(b.build())
                       .retrieve()
                       .bodyToMono(Long.class);
```

However in unit tests, I always receive resource = null. I use MockMVC for that:

```
MvcResult result = mvc.perform(
            multipart(getUri())
                .file("resource", new byte[] {65, 66, 67})
                .content(new byte[] {65, 66, 67})
                .accept(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
            .andExpect(status().isOk())
            .andReturn();
```

On the other hand, if I switch to using MultipartFile as parameter type in my Controller:

```
@RequestPart(name = "resource", required = false) MultipartFile multipartFile
```

It works if I pass a `MockMultipartFile` in unit tests, but I don't know how to pass a `MultipartFile` in my integration tests (and in the other service that uses my api). I tried implementing `org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile` by wrapping over my `ByteArrayResource`, but it doesn't look right (and doesn't work). I've spent way too much time on this already... Any recommendations?

P.S. I use StandardServletMultipartResolver

Comment: `MultipartFile` is correct for MVC controllers expecting to receive browser file uploads. But you say "rest services" so it's not clear what is the client of your controller - a web browser? A programmatic REST client?

"don't know how to pass a MultipartFile in my integration tests (and in the other service that uses my api). ": Assuming your integration tests are sending a request via HTTP, then you don't need to work out how to do this.

Comment: @artbristol my client is programmatic java rest client.

Comment: In that case there is no need for the complexity of multipart upload. I'd suggest you change the API to receive a file via direct PUT or POST, and the body of the request can be the file.

Comment: Thanks, that's how it's currently implemented. However I've got a request to make the request multipart so that we could pass a long list of parameters. And although it still works with file as a body, mock mvc test stopped working because multipart() builder does not digest it properly and post() gives me an exception when I cast my request to MultipartRequest.

Comment: I would not expect to be able to use MultipartFile from an HTTP client request. (I assume you realise that in an integration test, where HTTP is going on, you do not need to use matching classes on client and server). What happens when you use MultipartFile on the controller, and MultipartBodyBuilder/Resource on the client?

Comment: The file is added, but is not recognized as MultipartFile parameter on controller, thought it's still possible to extract it from request as a resource... Well, maybe that's the only way and I should give up trying to have it as a controller's method parameter...

Comment: The controller method parameter on the server should be fine. I think the problem is with your client code.

Comment: @artbristol yes, I figured, I couldn't find the right way to pass the file so that it'd be picked up as endpoint parameter, though I came up with an approach that works for me, after all (the answer below)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up with  `@RequestPart(name = "resource") Part part` in controller, which works well with both

```
ByteArrayResource resource = new ByteArrayResource(new byte[] {1, 2, 3});    
MultipartBodyBuilder b = new MultipartBodyBuilder();
b.part("resource", resource, MediaType.APPLICATION_PDF);
return webClient.post().uri(getUri()
    .contentType(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
    .syncBody(b.build())
    .retrieve()
    .bodyToMono(Long.class);
```

and

```
Part part = new MockPart("resource", new byte[]{1,2,3})
MvcResult result = mvc.perform(multipart(getUri())
    .part(part)
    .andExpect(status().isOk())
    .andReturn();
```